# Linux: Find out who was logged on when?

Tags: linux, ssh, user-accounts, sshd

I need to find out which user screwed up the ssh config.
There's nothing in anyone's bash history.
But I did see when a bunch of ssh-related errors in the logs that started at a specific time.

I'm thinking I could narrow it down by finding out who was logged on then.
Is this possible on linux?

(On a side note: this is for a class, the other users are my classmates, they're doing the same thing, and we're all aware that everyone is snooping on our activity)

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of lastlog. Check also `utmp(5)`.

Comment: It might pay to mention that **last** outputs the info ...

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `/var/log/secure` file

`/var/log/secure` Contains information related to authentication and authorization privileges. For example ssh logs all the messages here, including unsuccessful login.